# convert text to voice using twilio in php

Tags: php, twilio

I want to convert text to voice message and send to users phone no
currently i am using making call api with TwiMLTM

```
<?php
// Get the PHP helper library from twilio.com/docs/php/install
require_once('/path/to/twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php'); // Loads the library
// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
$sid = "xxx";
$token = "{{ auth_token }}";
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);
$call = $client->account->calls->create("+343443", "+3444", "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml", array(
"SendDigits" => "1234#",
"Method" => "GET"
));
echo $call->sid;
```

it is working,but this make call to user,but we need to voice message

Note : message is coming from textarea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio Evangelist here.

This is a little tricky. Twilio allows you to make phone calls, so if the dialled number is answered by voicemail, you can leave a message. If it is answered by a human being, then you'll need to interact with them. It is possible to use the [`if_machine` parameter when creating a call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls) to [detect an answering machine](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/voice/can-twilio-tell-whether-a-call-was-answered-by-a-human-or-machine). However you cannot 'send' a voice mail as if sending an SMS or an email. You need to make the call, and decide how to handle that depending on who/what answers.

You could try sending the message as an SMS however, which would deliver the exact text to the user:

```
$sms = $client->account->messages->sendMessage("+343443", "+3444", $message_text);
```

However, if the number you are sending to is not able to receive an SMS, then you need to make the call and interact with either a human or answering machine.

Best of luck!